# Try, Except:Pass on multiple lines

Tags: python, except, try-except

I'm writing another script for a program Called Abaqus, that plots XY data on a chart.... and part of my script changes the line styles based on if they are named a specific name....

So I have a bunch of different curve names and IF the chart contains that specific name, I want to execute the code to change the style... for example...

```
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S201-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(show=True)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S201-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(marker=FILLED_DIAMOND)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S201-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(size=2)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S201-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(color='#009afb')
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S247-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(show=True)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S247-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(marker=FILLED_DIAMOND)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S247-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(size=2)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S247-16'].symbolStyle.setValues(color='#009afb')
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_RELEASE'].symbolStyle.setValues(show=True)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_RELEASE'].symbolStyle.setValues(marker=FILLED_DIAMOND)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_RELEASE'].symbolStyle.setValues(size=2)
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_RELEASE'].symbolStyle.setValues(color='#009afb')   
    session.curves[PathNameNew+'_S205-18'].lineStyle.setValues(thickness=1)
```

I have about 50 different curve names with different styles and not all of those curves will be used every time, so I was thinking of using a  Try, except:pass method to achieve this... however that would mean I would have to do that for EACH curve name...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always make a closure function to do it for you:

```
def my_big_function():
    ...
    def set_symbolstyle_value(key, **kwargs):
        try:
            session.curves[PathNameNew + key].symbolStyle.setValues(**kwargs)
        except MyException:
            do_something()

    set_symbolstyle_value('_S201-16', show=True)
    set_symbolstyle_value('_S201-16', marker=FILLED_DIAMOND)
    ...
```

Functions are cheap. Don't be afraid to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Build a list of tuples, each of them containing two elements - the curve name and a dict of parameters like so:

```
[('somename',{'color':'blue', 'marker':FILLED_DIAMOND})...]
```

Then, lst being the list above, do the following:

```
for name, par in lst:
    if name in session.curves:
        session.curves[name].symbolStyle.setValues(**par)
```